How can I make Pytester reuse plugins?
I am trying to test fixtures that I have setup in my testing repository with PyTest 7.3.1 and Python3.8.
In this instance, I have fixtures that are making use the pytest-asyncio plugin. And the test functions are defined in separate modules.
Th first test is able to run successful, but the second test fails to hook on to the plugin, the second time around. This is regardless of test order; the second test always fail to use the plugin.
I understand that every new test executed by pytester invalidates the import cache before running the test, but I don't believe that is the problem here.
conftest.py

from pytest import fixture

@fixture(scope="session")
def fixture1(
    event_loop,  # Fixture implicit to the pytest_asyncio plugin
):
    return event_loop

@fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
async def fixture2():
    pass

Test modules
tests/.../test_fixture1.py

def test_fixture1(pytester):
    pytester.makepyfile(
        """
        from conftest import fixture1

        def test_simple(event_loop, fixture1):
            assert event_loop is fixture1
        """
    )
    result = pytester.runpytest()


tests/.../test_fixture2.py

def test_fixture2(pytester):
    pytester.makepyfile(
        """
        from conftest import fixture2

        def test_simple():
            pass
        """
    )
    result = pytester.runpytest()

When test_fixture1 is run first, t test_fixture2 returns a warning the fixture2 was never awaited
When test_fixture2 is tested first, test_fixture1 is unable to resolve the event loop fixture.
In both cases, this is a sign that pytester is unable to utilize the pytest-asyncio plugin.
I tried explicitly adding the plugin to the runpytest call, but this does little for the pytester environment to recognize the presence of the plugin.
Any thoughts or advice will help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@xirehat The code in this case is proprietary. But I will provide a gist.

Given the deprecation of support for python3.8 soon, we I have moved onto a newer version where this does not seem to be a problem anymore.

Instead of running the test using pytester.runpytest(), use pytester.runpytest_subprocess(). This should guarantee that everything is reloaded for each test. You can also use the command line flag --runpytest==subprocess.  See https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.Pytester.runpytest_subprocess for details.
Also, pytest 7.3.1 and Python 3.8 are pretty old; try running the tests on pytest 8.3.x and Python 3.12.x to see if there are bugs that have been fixed.
